# Ruby: Concise inline assignments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd like to create three stub models as follows:

```
@first_user, @second_user, @third_user = stub_model(User), stub_model(User), stub_model(User)
```

This works, but it seems there should be a more concise way of doing the right side of this thing, and I can't quite figure it out.

Please note that while they are all stubbed users, the three variables need to reference different stub models.

Comment: `@first_user, @second_user, @third_user = (1..3).collect { stub_model(User)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
@first_user, @second_user, @third_user = 3.times.map { stub_model(User) }
```

This just loops 3 times and maps the results into an array of users, which then gets expanded out to be assigned to the ivars.

Comment: Nice thing to learn... :)) thanks for teaching me :))

Comment: @Priti: You do know that `Array.new` can take a block for creating elements, right?

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks for reminding that..I forgot that block one. I have updated my answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
@first_user, @second_user, @third_user = Array.new(3){ stub_model(User) }
```

Sample examples :

```
Array.new(3){"foo"}.map(&:object_id)
# => [77834250, 77834230, 77834220]
Array.new(3){"12"}.map(&:object_id)
# => [77832800, 77832780, 77832770]
Array.new(3){{:a => 12 }}.map(&:object_id)
# => [77815300, 77815290, 77815270]
```

Comment: This doesn't produce unique objects. `(["foo"] * 3).map(&:object_id).uniq => [17017940]`

Comment: @ChrisHeald see I have updated.. :)

Comment: Still doesn't produce unique objects. `Array.new(3, "foo").map(&:object_id).uniq => [32495460]`

Comment: @ChrisHeald NO ... Its now OK see here `Array.new(3, "12").map(&:object_id)
# => [76336660, 76336660, 76336660]`

Comment: Those are 3 references to the same object. They are not unique objects. See how the IDs are all the same?

Comment: @ChrisHeald I have updated my answer with the correct version... please check :))

Comment: @Priti: Sorry, you already corrected that earlier, now I notice.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky I was fooled by `Array.new()`. Totally forgot the *block* form..No sorry... you guys are awesome.. :))